# Transformation of PDFs from cartesian to bispherical coordinates

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I want to transform the following equations into bispherical coordinates:

$$
\Delta f_x = -\frac{\kappa_s}{3} \left(4 u_{x,xx} + u_{x,yy} + 3 u_{y,xy}\right)\\
\Delta f_y = -\frac{\kappa_s}{3} \left(u_{y,xx} + 4 u_{y,yy} + 3 u_{x,xy}\right)
$$
With
$$u_x(x,y)$$ and $$u_y(x,y)$$
The new set of coordinates are defined as:

$$
x=c \cdot \frac{\sin(\xi) \cdot \cos(\phi)}{1-\cos(\xi)}\\
y=c \cdot \frac{\sin(\xi) \cdot \sin(\phi)}{1-\cos(\xi)}
$$

I tried to transform the equation from cartesian coordinates into the new ones, so I want to have $$\Delta f_{\xi}=...$$ and $$\Delta f_{\phi}=...$$ at the end.

At first I looked at the connection between $$u_x, u_y$$ and $$u_{\xi}, u_{\phi}$$

Afterwards I transformed the derivatives into the new coordinates.

My solution is:

$$
\Delta f_{\xi} =\frac{\kappa_s (\cos(\xi)-1)^2}{3c^2} \Bigg[ \frac{4}{\sin^2(\xi)} u_{\xi}  - \frac{4 \cos(\xi) }{\sin(\xi)}  u_{\xi, \xi} - \frac{5}{\sin^2(\xi)} u_{\phi, \phi} -4 u_{\xi, \xi \xi} - \frac{1}{\sin^2(\xi)}  u_{\xi, \phi \phi} - \frac{3}{\sin(\xi)}  u_{\phi, \xi \phi} \Bigg]
$$

$$
\Delta f_{\phi} =\frac{\kappa_s (\cos(\xi)-1)^2}{3c^2} \Bigg[  \frac{1}{\sin^2(\xi)} u_{\phi} + \frac{5}{\sin^2(\xi)} u_{\xi, \phi} - \frac{\cos(\xi)}{\sin(\xi)} u_{\phi, \xi} - \frac{3}{\sin(\xi)} u_{\xi, \xi \phi} - 1~ u_{\phi, \xi \xi} - \frac{4}{\sin^2(\xi)} u_{\phi, \phi \phi} \Bigg]
$$

I would appreciated if someone here could let me know wether the solution I got is right.

Comment: Can you recall what are bispherical coordinates (or simply give a web reference) with respect to bipolar coordinates ?

Comment: If you rotate the two-dimensional bipolar coordinate system about the axis that connects the two foci you get the bispherical coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the resulting transformed equations are alright. You can use `PDEtools` package of Maple to double check this much easier. The calculations can also be done by hand but they are somehow lengthy.

Let us denote by `PDE_X` and `PDE_Y` the equations in Cartesian as given above. The variable `tr` stands for the transformation equation giving $x$ and $y$ as functions of $\xi$ and $\phi$ as given above. Afterward, use `dchange` which takes as arguments the equation being transformed, i.e. `PDE_X` or `PDE_Y` and the transformation law `tr`.

By making use of the equations 
$$
\Delta f_{\xi} = -\Delta f_x \cos\phi - \Delta f_y \sin \phi \, , \\
\Delta f_{\phi} = -\Delta f_x \sin\phi + \Delta f_y \cos \phi \, ,
$$
together with 
$$
u_x = -u_\xi \cos\phi - u_\phi \sin \phi \, , \\
u_y = -u_\xi \sin\phi + u_\phi \cos \phi \, ,
$$
you will readily find your final results.

Bests